# "Once in a while" OR "Once in awhile"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, spacing

> **1.** Once in a while

OR

> **2.** Once in awhile

Which is the correct phrase? I'm thinking it's the first one, but I'm unable to find out for certain.

---

["a while" vs "awhile"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215138/a-while-vs-awhile) and [Correct usage of "awhile"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63954/correct-usage-of-awhile) were related but didn't answer the question

Comment: How do they not answer the question? 'Awhile' is an adverb so it can't be used in this sense.

Comment: I would certainly prefer to use "once in a while" -- it just looks better.  Dunno what the Pists might say.

Comment: @V0ight if that's ture, feel free to answer.

Comment: The answer is in the links you provided. Replace 'awhile' with any other adverb, like 'rarely' or 'seldom' and you'll see it makes no sense. 'Once in rarely'? 'Once in seldom'?

Comment: **Not a duplicate.** Yet another wrongly closed question. This one is about the specific phrase "once in a while". That one is about the adverb "awhile" and doesn't answer this question at all.

Answer (score 9):

The correct phrase is "Once in a while", as two separate words.

As "awhile" is an adverb, it *wouldn't* make sense to say "Once in awhile".
See @V0ight's comment:

> Replace 'awhile' with any other adverb, like 'rarely' or 'seldom' and you'll see it makes no sense. 'Once in rarely'? 'Once in seldom'?

Comment: I came here because I thought this was the correct phrasing, even though the editor in Google Mail (or is it Chrome's fault?) tried to tell me otherwise.